# "Converting Circular Structure to JSON" Error when logging data from axios get request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I'm currently making a GET request to an API using axios from my server with express.  My request comes through with a 200 status and I'm able to log the data that I need.

The problem is that after the request, I get this error:

> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

and the request just hangs instead of completing.

I've looked at other examples on Stackoverflow, but they all require some kind of "band-aid" solution which isn't what I'm looking for. If anyone can decipher what may be causing this issue I would greatly appreciate it!

Here is what my get request looks like within my server.js file

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')


import axios from 'axios';
import env from '../env.config.json';

const PORT = require('../env.config.json').SERVER.PORT;
const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, '../public');
import api from './routers/api-routing';

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
const port = PORT || 3000;
app.use(express.static(publicPath));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));

const io = socketIO(server);

app.get('/pingCrm', (request, response) => {

    var url = 'https://OURACCOUNTNAME.nocrm.io/api/v2/ping'
    var apikey = "API_KEY"

    axios.get(url, {
        headers: {'X-API-KEY': apikey, content_type: "json", accept: "application/json"}
    }).then(function(data){
        console.log(data.data);
        response.send(data);   
    }).catch(function(error){
        console.log("Error: " + error);
    })
})
```

Comment: You need `response.send(data.data);` (express converts the object to JSON to send it, and since you're sending the axios response object instead of the API response, and the axios response obj has a circular reference, you're greeted by the above error). I'd rename the parameter variable to something like `axiosReply` so you don't have to write `data.data`

Comment: Wow, can't believe that's what was doing it.  Thank you!

Comment: @ChrisG if I wanted to get the data from this request to client side, how would I do that?

Comment: Provided you fixed it accordingly, isn't that what you're already doing? You have established the `/pingCrm` route, and requesting it from the client side will already get the data

Comment: @ChrisG this request that I posted is being done server side.

Comment: Yes, the `axios.get()` is done server-side. But `app.get('/pingCrm',` sets up an endpoint that can be requested from the client. So if you open http://localhost:3000/pingCrm you should see the API result (since it is already being forwarded by your code, specifically by `response.send(data.data)`

Comment: @ChrisG I think I need to elaborate a little more.  Yes, I can get this request server side, and I can see it when I visit that url on the page. What I'm trying to get at is if I had another js file say _client.js_ in my react app, how do I retrieve the data from that request from my server within my _client.js_ file?

Comment: I see: `fetch('/pingCrm').then(reply => reply.json()).then(data => console.log(data))`

Comment: @ChrisG thanks for all your help!

Comment: You're welcome :)